# Stochastic dominance of Binomial and Poission

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-graphs

In order to investigate the size of the cluster of a given vetex in a random graph I need to use a fact about stochastic dominance that I don't know how to prove.

Namely, I am looking for a proof of the fact that $\text{Binom}(n, p)$ is stochastically dominated by $\text{Poi}(\lambda)$, where $\lambda=p(n+1)$ and $p\leq\frac{1}{n+1}.$

By stochastic dominace I mean the following:

$\mu$ is stochastically dominated by $\nu$ if $\mu(A)\leq\nu(A)$ for any upward closed event $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}$ (i.e. $x \in A$ and $x \leq y \implies y\in A$).

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: There is going to need to be some conditions on $p$. For instance, if $p=1$, then the binomial random variable is always $n$, but the probability that the poisson random variable with mean $n+1$ is less than $n$ is positive.

Comment: @DPoole  Thank you. You are right, I wasn't clear enogh,I clarified what I am really looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Richard, please see Theorem $1(f)$ in the following paper. The link is -
http://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/klenke/papers/binomial.pdf